# Can I change value of inline data attribute (data-parallax) using css?

Tags: css, html

On a Wordpress site, I want to turn off the theme parallax effect for certain pages. I'm not sure what library is used and I'd prefer to have a go at it via CSS. Code is:

```
<div id="primary" class=" page-header header-small" data-parallax="active" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">...</div>
```

So my guess was I would be able to target the "active" the same way you override inline [style]:

```
.page-child #primary[data-parallax] {
content:'none';
}
```

This didn't work so I went for the simpler

```
.page-child #primary[style] {
transform: none;
}
```

My question for the future is – is there a css way to target data- values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target the `div` element with `data-parallax` attribute set to `"active"` specifically, and turn off `translate3d` transform, use the following code:

```
[data-parallax="active"] {
  transform: translate3d(0);
}
```

---

To answer your question generally, these are the available attribute selectors you can use to target the element:

```
[data-value] {
  /* Attribute exists. */
}

[data-value="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has exact value "foo". */
}

[data-value*="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value contains value "foo" somewhere in it. */
}

[data-value~="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has value "foo" in a space-separated list somewhere. */
}

[data-value^="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value starts with "foo". */
}

[data-value|="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value starts with "foo" in a dash-separated list. */
}

[data-value$="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value ends with "foo". */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **yes**

Css gave us a possibility to manipulate CSS based on a value assigned to data-attribute. 
With that being said. Here is an example you could use to achieve it.

```
[data-parallax="foo"] //Where value is exactly foo
```